# loading external library with typescript front end app

Tags: javascript, typescript, axios

I am trying to use Axios in my front end typescript project and I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at file.ts:1
```

I am started learning typescript and thought to do some ajax call, here is the source code:

File.ts:

```
const axios = require('axios').default;
async function fetchInitData() {
    const resp = await  axios.default.get('http://localhost:8080/issues');
    return resp.data;
}

// const threads = require('worker_threads');
window.onload = async function () {
    let fetchInitData1 = fetchInitData();
    console.log(fetchInitData1);
    document.getElementById('totalbugcount').innerText = await fetchInitData1;

}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "type1",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "commonjs": "latest",
    "requirejs": "latest"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "build\\web\\assets\\js"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/scripts/**/*"
  ]
}
```

and after transpilling, this file gets generated:

```
var __awaiter = (this && this.__awaiter) || function (thisArg, _arguments, P, generator) {
    function adopt(value) { return value instanceof P ? value : new P(function (resolve) { resolve(value); }); }
    return new (P || (P = Promise))(function (resolve, reject) {
        function fulfilled(value) { try { step(generator.next(value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
        function rejected(value) { try { step(generator["throw"](value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
        function step(result) { result.done ? resolve(result.value) : adopt(result.value).then(fulfilled, rejected); }
        step((generator = generator.apply(thisArg, _arguments || [])).next());
    });
};
var __generator = (this && this.__generator) || function (thisArg, body) {
    var _ = { label: 0, sent: function() { if (t[0] & 1) throw t[1]; return t[1]; }, trys: [], ops: [] }, f, y, t, g;
    return g = { next: verb(0), "throw": verb(1), "return": verb(2) }, typeof Symbol === "function" && (g[Symbol.iterator] = function() { return this; }), g;
    function verb(n) { return function (v) { return step([n, v]); }; }
    function step(op) {
        if (f) throw new TypeError("Generator is already executing.");
        while (_) try {
            if (f = 1, y && (t = op[0] & 2 ? y["return"] : op[0] ? y["throw"] || ((t = y["return"]) && t.call(y), 0) : y.next) && !(t = t.call(y, op[1])).done) return t;
            if (y = 0, t) op = [op[0] & 2, t.value];
            switch (op[0]) {
                case 0: case 1: t = op; break;
                case 4: _.label++; return { value: op[1], done: false };
                case 5: _.label++; y = op[1]; op = [0]; continue;
                case 7: op = _.ops.pop(); _.trys.pop(); continue;
                default:
                    if (!(t = _.trys, t = t.length > 0 && t[t.length - 1]) && (op[0] === 6 || op[0] === 2)) { _ = 0; continue; }
                    if (op[0] === 3 && (!t || (op[1] > t[0] && op[1] < t[3]))) { _.label = op[1]; break; }
                    if (op[0] === 6 && _.label < t[1]) { _.label = t[1]; t = op; break; }
                    if (t && _.label < t[2]) { _.label = t[2]; _.ops.push(op); break; }
                    if (t[2]) _.ops.pop();
                    _.trys.pop(); continue;
            }
            op = body.call(thisArg, _);
        } catch (e) { op = [6, e]; y = 0; } finally { f = t = 0; }
        if (op[0] & 5) throw op[1]; return { value: op[0] ? op[1] : void 0, done: true };
    }
};
var axios = require('axios').default;
function fetchInitData() {
    return __awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function () {
        var resp;
        return __generator(this, function (_a) {
            switch (_a.label) {
                case 0: return [4 /*yield*/, axios.default.get('http://localhost:8080/issues')];
                case 1:
                    resp = _a.sent();
                    return [2 /*return*/, resp.data];
            }
        });
    });
}
// const threads = require('worker_threads');
window.onload = function () {
    return __awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function () {
        var fetchInitData1, _a;
        return __generator(this, function (_b) {
            switch (_b.label) {
                case 0:
                    fetchInitData1 = fetchInitData();
                    console.log(fetchInitData1);
                    _a = document.getElementById('totalbugcount');
                    return [4 /*yield*/, fetchInitData1];
                case 1:
                    _a.innerText = _b.sent();
                    return [2 /*return*/];
            }
        });
    });
};
//# 
//# sourceMappingURL=file.js.map
```

This is the line whereby the browser is pointing error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at file.ts:1
```

Comment: Were you able to learn about webpack and/or browserify to use require in client-side code?

Comment: Yes, today I got myself introduced to webpack,  now I need to study it may be then I will be able to use axios with typescript

Comment: Good luck! Webpack is almost a job of its own and causes a lot of headaches, but it is very powerful once configured. If you want something simpler, you can use browserify and tsify just to bundle up axios to test with. Keep us posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Axios and Typescript**

Axios recommends requiring the package in the following way for Typescript support:

> note: CommonJS usage
>
> In order to gain the TypeScript typings (for intellisense / autocomplete) while using CommonJS imports with require() use the following approach:

```
const axios = require('axios').default;

// axios.<method> will now provide autocomplete and parameter typings
```

[From the documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#note-commonjs-usage)

[TypeScript and Axios seem to be a common source of confusion, but they're working on it!](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1975)

[Very common](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/2226)

**Using 'require' in the browser**

Browsers don't support the NodeJS 'require' syntax. If javascript in the browser needs to use require to import packages, developers must add another build-step to resolve those dependencies. Webpack is commonly used with TypeScript, but browserify and others will get the job done! [Check out this answer that goes into more detail about require and the browser.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19059825/10437471)

Comment: Thanks for the update, I after doing the changes now I am getting: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at file.ts:1

Comment: Sounds like a bundle issue. You'll have to use something like webpack or browserify to resolve require statements in the browser. I updated my comment with more info!